# Hibernate HQL update with a subselect in set clause

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, orm

I'm trying to do an update in hibernate HQL with a subselect in a set clause like:

`update UserObject set code = (select n.code from SomeUserObject n where n.id = 1000)`

It isnt working, it is not supported?

Thanks

Udo

Comment: How does it fail, what message do you get?

Comment: @Pascal: AST unexpected node: query... so I think that maybe subselects in set clause are not supported, any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, discovered that you need to put bulk updates in side a transaction:

```
tr = session.getTransaction();
tr.begin();
updateQuery.executeUpdate();
tr.commit;
```

Answer (score 4):

From  the Hibernate documentation:

> #### [13.4. DML-style operations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)
>
> ...
>
> The pseudo-syntax for `UPDATE` and
>   `DELETE` statements is: `( UPDATE |
>   DELETE ) FROM? EntityName (WHERE
>   where_conditions)?`.
>
> Some points to note:
>
> - In the from-clause, the `FROM` keyword is optional
> - There can only be a single entity named in the from-clause. It can,
>     however, be aliased. If the entity
>     name is aliased, then any property
>     references must be qualified using
>     that alias. If the entity name is not
>     aliased, then it is illegal for any
>     property references to be qualified.
> - No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk
>     HQL query. **Sub-queries can be used
>     in the where-clause, where the
>     subqueries themselves may contain
>     joins.**
> - The where-clause is also optional.

While the documentation doesn't explicitly mentions a restriction about the set part, one could **interpret** that sub-queries are only supported in the where-clause. But...

I found an 4 years old (sigh) issue about bulk update problems ([HHH-1658](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1658)) and according to the reporter, the following works:

```
UPDATE Cat c SET c.weight = (SELECT SUM(f.amount) FROM Food f WHERE f.owner = c)
```

I wonder if using an alias in the from-clause would help. Looks like there is some weirdness anyway.